# R devel: Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘append’

Tags: r, append, package, warnings, cran

I am maintaining an R package that recently started throwing the following warning during `R CMD check packagename`:

`** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘append’`

(The package is called [phyloseq](http://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/), and the branch that is currently causing me this problem is [here](https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq/tree/empty-taxtable))

Refined subquestions:

1. - So the "multiple methods tables" part, this seems to imply that I have two dependent packages with a collision over dispatch for the `append` method. Right?
2. - I don't have a function/method named `"append"` in this package, and don't import any.
3. - I was able to reproduce the warning message in a new R session by simply loading two of the packages in R at the same time, one of which ([RJSONIO](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html)) is a second-level dependency -- by which I mean one of my dependencies ([biom](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biom/)) depends on it, but not mine:
     `library("RJSONIO");library("Biostrings")`

Which throws the warning in the R session:

`multiple methods tables found for ‘append’`

And naturally, `append` is exported in the `NAMESPACE` file of both RJSONIO and [Biostrings](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html). What I don't understand is why this should cause a problem when loading my package. The packages I directly depend on (Biostrings-2.28.0, biom-0.3.8) are not fully imported -- certainly not importing any `append` methods. How else could this conflict arise?

**Workaround**:

If I update Biostrings to the "devel" version, 2.29.2, then the warning appears to go away. Most users will not do this, however, and I'd still like to understand how this collision is even possible, given the way I specifically imported functions and classes from these packages rather than full `Import` or `Depends`.

Comment: Maybe some of the packages yours depends on have functions called `append` (in addition to the base package version).

Comment: Sounds plausible. Too bad the warning message doesn't give the name of the offending package.

Comment: The error seems to get thrown during package load after the [nlme package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) gets loaded. It is a dependency of at least one of my dependencies, but I don't depend on `nlme` directly.

Comment: Could it be a function defined for a class as in: `library(sos)`, `a1 <- ???"append"`, `cbind(a1$Function[grep("^append",a1$Function)],a1$Package[grep("^append",a1$Function)])
`. Could one of your function calls depend on one of these?

Comment: I tried that `???"append"`, throws an error. Tried modified version with `help.search`, but that didn't give me anything. If I knew anything about `append` in nlme or what else might use it, I'd have some footing. Was hoping someone on here would already be super familiar with `append` and its collisions between packages. I also thought the namespace structure would take care of this. No idea what the issue is.

Comment: I updated the question for a specific shortcut to reproduce this error simply by loading two of the dependencies in the same R session.